# ¿Cómo puedo extraer el número de un campo en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, funciones, variables

Me gustaría saber si es que existe una `función`, o alguna forma en donde yo pueda extraer el número de un campo cualquiera.

Por ejemplo de`'Casa1234'` yo solamente quiero ver `'1234'`

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo usando el `CAST` y convirtiendo tu cadena a valores numéricos sin signo `UNSIGNED` ejemplo (Solo que este método debe empezar por números y luego texto):

```
SELECT CAST('1234CASA' AS UNSIGNED)
```

O, podrías usar esta función que suelo utilizar:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION ObtenNumeros(cadena VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE EncuentraNumero VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE CualNumero VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE ObtenCaracter VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE Cuanto INTEGER DEFAULT 1;

    IF LENGTH(cadena) > 0 THEN
        WHILE(Cuanto <= LENGTH(cadena)) DO
            SET ObtenCaracter = SUBSTRING(cadena, Cuanto, 1);
            SET EncuentraNumero = FIND_IN_SET(ObtenCaracter, '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'); 
            IF EncuentraNumero > 0 THEN
                SET CualNumero = CONCAT(CualNumero, ObtenCaracter);
            END IF;
            SET Cuanto = Cuanto + 1;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN CAST(CualNumero AS UNSIGNED);
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;    
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes romper el campo en varias partes en la misma consulta o usar la parte que te interese:

1. Campo completo.
2. Campo con el valor numérico.
3. Campo con el resto de la cadena.

Supongamos que tenemos un campo llamado `'micampo'` que contiene la cadena `'casa123'` o `'123casa'` y que tenemos una tabla llamada `'mitabla'` que contiene ese campo.

La consulta SQL a ejecutar para obtener el valor numérico por un lado, y la cadena por otro, sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT
`micampo`,
@num := CONVERT(`micampo`, SIGNED) AS numero,
SUBSTRING(`micampo`, LENGTH(@num) + 1) AS texto FROM `mitabla`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el `SUBSTRING`, tu nombre del campo donde se almacena `Casa1234` y `MITABLA` es el nombre de tu tabla.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Casa1234',5,6) FROM 'MITABLA'
```

El resultado sería:

> `1234`

Comment: ¿y qué tal que se trataran de diferentes cadenas con diferentes longitudes?

Comment: No entendí muy bien tu pregunta, pero mi respuesta fue según la pregunta de @CamilaJaviera, sólo quiere extraer el valor numérico del dato **'Casa1234'**

Comment: Me refiero a que `Casa1234` es únicamente un ejemplo, de acuerdo a la pregunta y dado que solo es un ejemplo, podrían existir otros casos, tales como `Edificio098765`